Why do we say וצוונו in the Chanukah menorah blessing if it was not commanded by God?
This mitzvah was not commanded by God!
I do understand there is the (I believe it might be a biblical) commandment to follow the direction of the sages.
But why would the sages be so inclined to devise such a blessing that is a bit misleading perhaps? Unless one of the sages received a prophecy to do this.
Other commandments that we say blessings on have a source in the Torah or were commanded by God, but not Chanukah. Purim also perhaps...
